# change code font using mcode package

Tags: fonts, listings, matlab

I'm using `mcode` package to insert into my document matlab code. I would change the default font. what command I should use to get this font?

[image]

Comment: It looks like *Latin Modern Mono*. It should be the default monospaced font. If it's not and you have it installed and if you can use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX you could try adding `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}` in your preamble.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mcode.sty` file has a "Customize here" section.

Change

```
\def\lstbasicfont{\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont}
```

into

```
\def\lstbasicfont{\ttfamily}
```

and you'll get the default fixed width font instead of Courier. Or

```
\def\lstbasicfont{\fontfamily{lmtt}{\selectfont}}
```

that will choose the Latin Moder Typewriter font, which has also a boldface variant.