# Weaving MATLAB m-file into a LaTeX File

Tags: matlab

Hopefully this is a simple question: is there a simple, fast, and general method of porting the the text of an m-file verbatim into LaTeX and have it appear as it does in VI, i.e. ignore all of the MATLAB nomenclature, like % and so on, to appear as standard text consistent with whatever package I am using?

Comment: I;m not sure perhaps you simply want `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` or if you need fancier formatting look at the fancyvrb or listings packages/

Comment: There are a couple of packages that can help you directly. The minted package as is described in the question and answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84777/19384 and the m-code package as explained on this question and answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85764/19384

Comment: Yeah, that I was it. I just found it. Thanks so much for your reply. Have a good day...

Comment: Another more sophisticated question: is there a method that treats an arbitrary .txt like, say, and .eps file, with a LT command that allows the .txt to be read in and compiled, like we treat figures. This would automate the entire process.

Comment: @JohnSevic Perhaps you should take this comment and add it as a new question. However, please, check first if something similar has been posted already.

Comment: I did, and saw something for R, but not MATLAB or Mathematica.

Comment: @JohnSevic Could you explain in more details, what your copy of VI does with the MATLAB file because on my computer the m-files are only highlighted. So try the [mcode package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package). It does what I imagine you would wish.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Inline MATLAB code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69382/5764); [inserting MATLAB code in the appendix](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75116/5764). The [`mcode` package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package) uses [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) with a pre-defined format that matched that of MATLAB. It also supports `\lstinputlistings` for inclusion of the `.m`-file.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).